# Make angular see content created by jquery

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a large enterprise application, our application uses jQuery, and we would like to concentrate on using angular, we can not instantly remove all jQuery code and therefore we have to deal with things that are already present in the system. One of the most frequent things that are blocking us from using angular is a presence of the following code

```
$.ajax('/HtmlController', {...}).then(function(html) {
    $('someElement').replaceWith(html);
});
```

we can not remove it for now, because it would break up something in the system. Instead we would like to move to angular smoothly, step by step. And one of the first steps we need to make is apply angular's bindings within html returned and replaced with jQuery. In other words we need to put the following markup into `html` variable

```
...
1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }}
...
```

And we need it to get executed by angular, but unfortunately angular doesn't see the newly injected html, how is it possible to make angular see it?

Comment: Try using `$( 'someElement' ).replaceWith( $interpolate(html)($scope) );` Don't forget to add `$interpolate` using dependency injection.

Comment: I can't change replaceWith code, this change will be reflected in more than 100 dialogs that might have custom javascript with a lot of dependencies on html structure, I need to interpolate somehow existing html. Is it possible to accomplish somehow?

Comment: Well, I am pretty new with AngularJS but, if the `someElement` is within a controller, you may wants to use a `$timeout` to check its it's html using `var value = $('[ng-controller="yourController"]').html()` and call `value = $interpolate(value)({})` on it. Or you may overrides `$.fn.replaceWith` but I am not sure how you could then, execute Angular's code within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to compile the element and link it with an scope. Assuming you have an angular page, something like this would work:

```js
$.ajax('/HtmlController', {...}).then(function(html) {
  var dom = $('someElement');
  var el = angular.element(dom), scope = el.scope(), 
      $compile = el.injector().get('$compile');

  scope.$apply(function(){
    dom.replaceWith($compile($(html))(scope));  
  });
});
```

Here is a simple example: http://plnkr.co/edit/mRhsZV5DahfCjMWkP2My?p=preview